# Django. How to expire all user passwords?

Tags: django

I have a site with a few thousands registered users. In the unfortunate event when someone steals passwords from my database, I would like to have a *plan A* and a *plan B*. I guess plan B would be to change all user passwords (using a small python script and a random password generator) and email those new ones to the users. I can do that, easily.

Plan A (which sounds more appropriate, I am not sure how to do it) would be to force users to create new passwords by expiring the old ones, the first time they visit the page after the attack.

Does Django have a feature like this? How can it be done efficiently and fast?

Note: My User/UserProfile Models at the moment have not been designed with that situation in mind.

Comment: Where is user's session located (if db, you need to clear session collection/table)? You just need to drop all active sessions from _your_ server

Comment: Plan A is much better then Plan B I think. You will need to clear the session DB and create a 'forgot your password' view or similar. In the meantime you just need to blank all passwords in the DB and wait for them to be reset by the user.

Comment: user sessions are located in the DB.

Comment: @TimmyO'Mahony forgot password functionality sounds reasonable. if session is stored in db. +1

Comment: @TimmyO'Mahony `FYI` just checked password field in User model is a required field. You can't set empty value there.

Comment: Ah didn't think of that but in the past I've just changed it to `$` or something similar. Again, once it can't be generated by the hash function it will never validate

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first thing you should do is deactivate all users so they cannot login. One way to do that is with [`set_unusable_password()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User.set_unusable_password). This will invalidate all passwords; or you can set [`is_active`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User.is_active) to `False`. This will disable the user wholesale.

Next, you can have users reset their passwords. There are [built-in helpers and forms](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/default/#module-django.contrib.auth.views) for that as well.

Comment: +1 for link to `set_unusable_password`, I never knew about that.

Comment: Thanks about the `set_unusable_password()`. So lets assume that I have made all passwords unusable and in some way forced users into automatic redirect to a password change form. Will the new password be usable, again?

Comment: Yes, if you replace the unusable password with a different password, it will be usable again.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion you should go for Plan B. Check [Management Commands](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-management-commands/):

```
from django.core.management.base import NoArgsCommand
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Command(NoArgsCommand):
    help = _('Change password of all users.')
    def handle_noargs(self, **options):
        users = User.objects.all()
        for user in users:
            # generate random password
            random_pwd = 'some random password'
            user.set_password(random_pwd)
            user.save()
            # send email to user
```